# Wrong values in calculating Frequency using FFT

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, fft

I'm getting wrong frequency, I don't understand why i'm getting wrong values.since i have calculating as per instructions followed by stackoverflow.
I've used FFT from
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/FFT.java.html
and complex from
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html

```
audioRec.startRecording();
audioRec.read(bufferByte, 0,bufferSize);
for(int i=0;i<bufferSize;i++){
    bufferDouble[i]=(double)bufferByte[i];    
    }
Complex[] fftArray = new Complex[bufferSize];
    for(int i=0;i<bufferSize;i++){
    fftArray[i]=new Complex(bufferDouble[i],0);
    }
    FFT.fft(fftArray);
double[] magnitude=new double[bufferSize];
for(int i=0;i<bufferSize;i++){
      magnitude[i] = Math.sqrt((fftArray[i].re()*fftArray[i].re()) + (fftArray[i].im()*fftArray[i].im()));
    }
double max = 0.0;
int index = -1;
for(int j=0;j<bufferSize;j++){
    if(max < magnitude[j]){
            max = magnitude[j];
        index = j;
        }
    }
    final int peak=index * sampleRate/bufferSize;
    Log.v(TAG2, "Peak Frequency = " + index * sampleRate/bufferSize);
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textView.append("---"+peak+"---");
            }
        });
```

i'm getting values like 21000,18976,40222,30283 etc...
Please help me.....
Thank you..

Comment: You should try running on clean data with known synthesized sinusoids.  You don't seem to be looking at magnitude so your results may simply be noise.  And it is not obvious if you are using a window function.

Comment: What is your sample rate and buffer size?  What does your input signal look like?

Comment: @chris since I'm new to dsp, please explain in programming...

Comment: @hotpaw2 sample rate is 44100, buffer size is 4096, and input signal is mic buffer date from android phone

Comment: Drop the microphone and substitute a calculated sine wave of configurable frequency to experiment with until you get correct results.  When you can recover that, then display the magnitude and note how the detected magnitude varies with frequency even when the input is constant... to fix that, go read up on window functions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Pardon me,please explain in coding, i not getting what your'e trying to explain.

Comment: Replace the microphone with a program that calculates a sine wave and experiment with that to understand how this all works. If you do not understand what that means, you need to do some substantial reading and research before you start playing with FFTs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton and hotpaw2
Please refer this[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882835/incorrect-peak-frequency-in-jtransform). I've changed algorithm fft to jtransform, still i'm stuck with this....Please help me.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is this way to calculate sine wave..
'buffer size=4096;
sampleSize=44100;
 for(int i=0;i<bufferSize;i++){
     pure_sine[i]=Math.sin((2*Math.PI*i)/sampleSize);
     Log.i(Tag, "sine_Wave=="+pure_sine[i]);
    // disp.append(pure_sine[i]+"-->");
     
    }'

Comment: Now try multiplying i by various factors to change the generated frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source code is almost fine. The only problem is that you search for the peaks through the full spectrum, i.e. from 0 via Fs/2 to Fs.

For any real-valued input signal (which you have) the spectrum between Fs/2 and Fs (=sample frequency) is an exact mirror of the spectrum between 0 and Fs/2 (I found [this nice background explanation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/4827)). Thus, for each frequency there exist two peaks with ***almost*** identical amplitude. I'm writing 'almost' because due to limited machine precision they are not necessarily ***exactly*** identical. So, you randomly find the peak in the first half of the spectrum which contains the frequencies below the Nyquist frequency (=Fs/2) or in the second half of the spectrum with the frequencies above the Nyquist frequency.

If you want to correct the mistake yourself, stop reading here. Otherwise continue:

Just replace

```
for(int j=0;j<bufferSize;j++){
```

with

```
for(int j=0;j<=bufferSize/2;j++){
```

in the source code you presented.

P.S.: Typically, it is better to apply a window function to the analysis buffer (e.g. a Hamming window) but for your application of peak picking it won't change results very much.

Comment: sorry for the delay....
I've dropped FFT nd stick with Zero Crossing. Refer this [link](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/audio/processing/ZeroCrossing.java).
It doesn't seems major difference in frequency detection.If you have any suggestions, please share with me.Thank you

Comment: I will have a look at the link. Meanwhile, you could accept my answer as it is very likely that the wrong values of your alg resulted from searching also through the mirror spectrum. Might be interesting for other readers.

Comment: Actually, this kind of rough zero-crossing analysis only works if the harmonics are very low compared with the fundamental and only with a good S/N-radio and only if you analyse a monophonic signal. In all other cases the estimate gets more or less worse.

Comment: Thank you very much.I've tried that,but still i'm getting lot's of noise.pls explain it clearly.

Comment: With the FFT-based extraction described here, or the Zero-Crossing from these comments?

Comment: Did you apply the correction from my answer? Did you also add a window function?

Comment: yeah, i've applied your correction.Sorry to say i don't know how to apply window function. Please give some codes for window function, Thank you.

Comment: If you have any other working example for detecting peak frequency,.. Please share with me. Thanks

Comment: See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21497888/1986583 Code for a window function is 2nd question, and we should not discuss it in the comments. You say, your window size is 4096 and sample rate is 44100kHz. This means that you use a window size of almost 93ms. Which frequencies do you intend to detect? Do the signals you record by the mic contain perfectly steady frequencies?